# Operations error with ldap_add in ldapjs tutorial

Tags: node.js, ldap, ldapjs

I am following the [ldapjs guide](http://ldapjs.org/guide.html) and using the [/etc/passwd server](http://ldapjs.org/examples.html#etcpasswd-server) code example. It's working fine with the `ldapsearch` commands, but I get an `Operations error (1)` when adding a new entry with `ldapadd`.

```bash
pi@radiuspi:~/code/ldap $ sudo ldapadd -H ldap://localhost:1389 -x -D cn=root -w secret -f ./user.ldif
adding new entry "cn=ldapjs, ou=users, o=myhost"
ldap_add: Operations error (1)
        matched DN: ou=users,o=myhost
```

It successfully reads the `user.ldif` file since it's adding a new entry for `cn=ldapjs`.

```
dn: cn=ldapjs, ou=users, o=myhost
objectClass: unixUser
cn: ldapjs
shell: /bin/bash
description: Created via ldapadd
```

But afterwards it shows the Operations error. I don't know why it still prints the `matched DN: ou=users,o=myhost` line, but it does not add the new entry when verifying with ldapsearch.

The ssh terminals with the ldap server and commands:
[image: ssh terminal to rpi]

The ldap server is started with root/sudo. I have tried this on both WSL Ubuntu and on a Raspberry Pi with the same error.

- Node.js v20.5.1, ldap-utils 2.4.57